# Best name for an API endpoint that checks if a username is valid or not

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions, restful-architecture

I'm going to design a RESTful API which checks if there's anything wrong (e.g. duplicate, invalid characters, or names listed in the blacklist ... ) with the username provided by the caller.

The API should return the check result (valid or invalid) to the caller so that the caller knows if he can use this username or not.

How can I name the API endpoint?

I originally thought that `GET /checkUserName/{username}` or `GET /isUserNameValid/{username}` are good names for my API. But I'm not sure if they are really good. And I don't know how to convenience others to accept the names I came up with.

`GET` is the http method. `username` is a parameter provided by the caller.

I've read the following two articles:

[10 best practices for better restful api](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/)

[RESTful API Designing guidelines — The best practices](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9)

But it seems like that the name of my API cannot fit into all the guidelines described in the above articles.

One of the guidelines says

> Use nouns but no verbs

By following this guideline, `GET /checkUserName/{username}` is not appropriate. Because it contains the verb `check`.

`GET /isUserNameValid/{username}` is not appropriate, either. Because `is` is a verb.

So what's the best name for the API if I have to follow the guidelines of RESTful design?

I couldn't think of an appropriate name that contains no verb.

Comment: `POST` `{username:'xyz',password:'blah'}` to `/authenticate` is good, because authenticate means to verify credentials are correct.

Comment: Or maybe /users/{username}/isValid ?

Comment: The API doesn't have to check the password that belongs to the user.

Comment: For including a new service on the "users" context for validation, i would go "/users/{username}/validation". If this validation procedure is something you want to expand in the future for other resources, you can do a preffix like "/validation/users/{username}".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to build an RPC API but want to call it REST. :)

A little [background information on the differences](https://blog.apisyouwonthate.com/understanding-rpc-rest-and-graphql-2f959aadebe7).

Normally I'd try to suggest refactoring, as validation in general is best handled on the server-side, with JSON Schema being defined and shared with the frontend so that they can also use a JSON Schema validator locally and match the validation.

The "duplicate" criteria is the one thing that JSON Schema could not validate against, and I'm sure the use-case is one of those username boxes that gives instant feedback on how good the username is before submitting the actual form.

So a few approaches.

### 1.) Microservice

Buzzword yes, but often when it comes time for a tiny little endpoint that needs to do one specific thing, especially if that thing is a bit RPC and the rest of the API is a REST API, I use a single little service.

Often APIs for the sake of RAD are written in PHP or Ruby and have some giant framework, but for some little system that needs to work quick often I've used something smaller like Go.

You could of course use the same language and the usual Sinatra vs Rails difference comes into play. This could just be a single RPC

### 2.) REST Crowbar

So to make it be RESTful, you just want to create a new resource type, which would need to be something like:

```
POST /username-checks

{ "username": "foo" }
```

I don't much like this, but it could be due to there being a substantially better design that we've not even considered yet.

### 3.) Big Brother

As soon as the registration form has something like an email entered, save everything that has been filled out in the form so far.

This *could* be a `POST /users` with the populated fields and default to having a status of "potential", or it could be some other `POST /user-potential` resource. That's up to you, but the idea of posting very little, very early has two benefits.

1. You can do abandoned cart style reminders to people to "finish their account", which is becoming increasingly common in the e-commerce world
2. Once you have created this resource, you have a UUID which you can [PATCH](https://medium.com/apis-you-wont-hate/put-vs-patch-vs-json-patch-208b3bfda7ac) against.

Trying to PATCH with an invalid username would give you validation errors.

```
PATCH /users/<uuid>

{ username: "admin" }
```

For your errors, consider using [RFC 7807: API Problems](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), it's fantastic.

*I'm not trying to set up a false trichotomy here, there's probably a few other approaches but I'd really consider 1 or 3, with 2 being a maybe I threw in for the sake of giving a complete answer.*

Answer (score 3):

I actually prefer this

```
POST /usernames/:username/check
```

since it turns `username` into a resource which paves the way for any future API endpoints dealing with usernames, such as

```
POST /usernames/:username/exists
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think that `GET /usernames/:username/check` is more appropriate. Because I'm getting data from the API endpoint. `POST` is used creating data.

Answer (score 0):

What I plan on doing is by treating the field(s) I want to validate against some rules separately from the object they belong to, by creating a sub resource of that field underneath the object that it belongs to and to then try to Create (POST) a value to it. If it returns 409, one already exists for that. If it returns 200 OK or 201 Created then it's valid. 400 means it failed validation.

Or, I was thinking of doing a GET against a specific instance of that field (data entered by user) and if it returns 404, then it's unique and doesn't already exist. I don't think this works as well if you need to do some kind of other business rule validation other than it being unique.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for the validity of any input and verifying that over an API needs a slight adjustment in your question to get to a good answer, I think.

**TL;DR:** The API isn't going to tell you whether the user is unique, the API is going to tell you if a user exists.

Let's go into *why*.

**Option 1:** You create an API endpoint that checks for the validity of just one value of an object, e.g.:

`GET /users/:uuid/unique`

It would give you an HTTP 200 if it is unique, or HTTP 409 (Conflict). But the latter is relatively strange, and HTTP 200 suggests "everything is fine", so this way of working is not very intuitive.

**Option 2:** Instead, I opted to go with a simple search:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
POST /users/search
{
  "uuid": "fdd8d2f3-7f22-4140-b331-626f5f8e015e",
  "slug": "john-doe"
}
```

(If you want to implement an `and` or `or` search, you could look at [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) to see how their query syntax looks. I left that kind of complexity out for the sake of simplicity.)

Then in your code, you could have a function or method called `isUniqueUser(searchCriteria)` which can return:

1. `false`, meaning that the user exists, the API got an `HTTP 200`;
2. `true`, meaning that the user does **not** exist, the API got an `HTTP 404`.

The API is not concerned with checking for the uniqueness of objects, not until you create one that might be a duplicate, but it can perfectly find an existing record (or not) and suggest the same thing.